# Monte Carlo with simsem and lavaan: "Error in D3.LRT ... Try the D2 pooling method."

Tags: r, montecarlo, r-mice, r-lavaan

My goal is to generate a list of dataframes from a `lavaan` model using `simsem::sim`. Depending on if the `dataOnly` argument is TRUE or FALSE, `simsem::sim` will either generate a `SimResult` object (which includes generated data plus parameter values, fit indices, etc.) or just a list of the generated dataframes.

If I impose any missingness on the generated dataframes, I am incapable of generating the full `SimResult` object. I can either generate a `SimResult` object with no missingness or I can generate a list of dataframes with missingness. Trying to generate the `SimResult` object with missingness gives the below error message, but I couldn't find any argument for `sem`, `simsem::miss`, or `simsem::sim` where I could specify to use the D2 pooling method. Any help would be appreciated.

> #> Error in D3.LRT(object, h1 = h1, useImps = useImps, asymptotic = asymptotic, : D3 test statistic could not be calculated. Try the D2 pooling method.

```
set.seed(123)
suppressMessages(library(mice))
suppressMessages(library(lavaan))
suppressMessages(library(simsem))

data(mtcars)
model <- 'gear ~ carb'
fit <- lavaan::sem(model, data = mtcars)
make_missing <- simsem::miss(package = "mice", m = 2, maxit = 2, seed = 123)

thisworks <- simsem::sim(
  nRep = 10,
  model = fit,
  n = 5)
#> Progress: 1 / 10 
#> Progress: 2 / 10 
#> Progress: 3 / 10 
#> Progress: 4 / 10 
#> Progress: 5 / 10 
#> Progress: 6 / 10 
#> Progress: 7 / 10 
#> Progress: 8 / 10 
#> Progress: 9 / 10 
#> Progress: 10 / 10
class(thisworks)
#> [1] "SimResult"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "simsem"

thisdoesnotwork <- simsem::sim(
  nRep = 10,
  model = fit,
  n = 5,
  miss = make_missing)
#> Progress: 1 / 10
#> Error in D3.LRT(object, h1 = h1, useImps = useImps, asymptotic = asymptotic, : D3 test statistic could not be calculated. Try the D2 pooling method.

thispartiallyworks <- simsem::sim(
  nRep = 10,
  model = fit,
  n = 5,
  dataOnly = TRUE,
  miss = make_missing)
#> Progress: 1 / 10 
#> Progress: 2 / 10 
#> Progress: 3 / 10 
#> Progress: 4 / 10 
#> Progress: 5 / 10 
#> Progress: 6 / 10 
#> Progress: 7 / 10 
#> Progress: 8 / 10 
#> Progress: 9 / 10 
#> Progress: 10 / 10
class(thispartiallyworks)
#> [1] "list"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to generate a list of dataframes from a `lavaan` model using `simsem::sim`

I'm confused, because neither the `lavaan()` nor `sim()` function returns a `data.frame` object.

> Depending on if the `dataOnly` argument ...

OK, so you do want the generated data (in a list), to which the model would be fit by `lavaan()` within `sim()`.  In that case, the reason you are getting complete data is because you didn't choose any missing-data mechanism when you created the `SimMissing` object `make_missing`.  Observe an alternative to your `thispartiallyworks` example:

```
make_missing <- miss(package = "mice", m = 2, maxit = 2,
                     seed = 123, pmMCAR = .3)
set.seed(123)
incompleteList <- sim(nRep = 10, model = fit, n = 5,
                      dataOnly = TRUE, miss = make_missing)
incompleteList # list of data.frames with NAs
```

The `thisdoesnotwork` example is still a problem, but now because `mice()` detects collinearity (no surprise with only 5 observations, some of which are incomplete).  Increasing the sample size to `n=50` got me back to your original error, to which there is no solution implemented in `simsem` (i.e., there is no way to pass arguments to `semTools` methods for `lavaan.mi` objects; see more on this below).  But I suspect the error may be due to your model being saturated (*df* = 0).  When I ran a larger model (with *df* > 0), it worked fine:

```
model <- ' mpg ~ carb + gear
   carb + gear ~ cyl
'
fit <- lavaan::sem(model, data = mtcars)
thisworksnow <- simsem::sim(
    nRep = 10,
    model = fit,
    n = 50,
    miss = make_missing)
```

When I add the direct effect of `cyl` on `mpg` and the residual covariance between `carb` and `gear`, the model is once again saturated, so the pooling method does not work.

```
model <- '  mpg ~ carb + gear + cyl
   carb  + gear ~ cyl
   carb ~~ gear
'
fit <- lavaan::sem(model, data = mtcars)
cannotwork <- simsem::sim(
    nRep = 10,
    model = fit,
    n = 50,
    miss = make_missing) # original error
```

Since `sim` does not have a mechanism to "turn off" the collection of `fitMeasures()` to store in the `SimResult` object's `@fit` slot, I suppose a solution would be to update `semTools:::D3.LRT()` to return a pooled `chisq` and `df` = 0 for saturated models.  I posted an issue on GitHub to get that done, so hopefully this error can be avoided in the future.  You can watch for updates there:

https://github.com/simsem/semTools/issues/113